# AWS Documentation is slow to scroll through

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, browser

For some reason, whenever I scroll through the documentation (particularly, the developer guides) of AWS, the scroll is very flickery. On the other hand, when I save the raw HTML and browse through the docs "offline" (using [this Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-page-we/dhhpefjklgkmgeafimnjhojgjamoafof) for easier replication), it scrolls smoothly. Checking the performance of the actual (non-offline) page render using Chrome, it looks like the brunt of the work is being done during "Painting."

Actual

[image]

Offline

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: What browser and OS versions do you use?
What link are you scrolling?

Comment: Chrome `Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)`, Mac OS Catalina `10.15.2`, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-idp-settings.html

Comment: Does Safari or Firefox lag while scrolling this page?

Comment: I don't have Firefox installed but it's actually much faster on Safari

Comment: I have reported this to the AWS Documentation team and they are working on a fix. It seems to only affect Chrome on Mac.

Comment: @AlleyOOP The documentation team has made an update based on this feedback. It apparently only affected Chrome with certain sized screens. Could you please check whether it is working better for you now?

Comment: @John Rotenstein it definitely feels faster. The painting time has dropped too. Not as fast and smooth as safari, though.